# The meaning of verbs with prefix "раз-\рас-" and postfix "-ся"

Tags: лексикон, морфология, semantics, приставки

Can the following words be used in any context? I even doubt that some of them exist, but I cannot think of any reason why they shouldn't:

> разработаться
>   расчитаться (from читать)
>   раздуматься

On the other hand, words like the following are completely normal:

> раскричаться
>   расписаться (meaning "get into a good mood for writing, gather speed when writing something")
>   размечтаться

I was wondering what is the meaning that "рас-ся" adds to the meaning of the verb, is this derivation regular and if yes, why the words from the first group sound strange (do they?).

Comment: Check Tsvetaeva's poem for further insights on "pac-":
http://slova.org.ru/cvetaeva/rasstoianieversty/

Comment: Только в школу расходилась, да за партой рассиделась, да в тетрадке расписалась, да на доску разгляделась, в переменку расшумелась, всех подруг расслушалась – вдруг каникулы зачем-то на меня обрушились!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The meaning you're referring to is the one of *start doing something and become good at it*.  For example, *распеться* means _to start singing and get to the point where you "warm up" enough to be able to do it well.  There are some deviations but all around the same meaning:

- Your example of *раскричаться* is commonly used when somebody is screaming for some time, meaning that they've "warmed up" enough to be good at it.
- *Размечтаться* is normally used when a person comes up with absolutely unrealistic and unachievable desires, the state where in English one could respond by "dream on".
- *Разработаться* and *расчитаться* in the sense that you mentioned in your post are not commonly used but I've encountered them in literature and regular speech and even use them myself once in a while.

There are also some exceptions to the structural meaning of such words, for example:

- *Расписаться* usually means *to put one's signature to/in/on something* and **not** *to start writing and become good at it*, although this second meaning is sometimes used as well, especially when referring to writers.
- *Рассчитаться* means *to pay off* or *to settle the debt* and **not** *to start and get good at counting*
- *Разобраться* is closest in meaning *to figure out*

Note that such words cannot be created from all verbs.  However most imperfect verbs (несовершенные глаголы) сould work while pretty much none of the perfect verbs (совершенные глаголы) would not.

Comment: Can you please give some examples of "расчитаться" derived from verb "читать"?

Comment: Btw, don't you think that "раскричаться" rather means "to start scream a lot and\or at everybody around and\or without any good reason" than "to warm up screaming so that one is good at it"?

Comment: @Olga _раскричаться_ doesn't necessarily means that they they are screaming at everybody around or without any good reason.  Literally it means that somebody started screaming and has been screaming for a while.  The part of "getting good at it" is inferred here :)

Comment: @Olga about расчитаться, for example, from "Дневники 1923-1925" Пришвина: "Читал «Голубые бобры» в Союзе Писателей. Не успел я **расчитаться**, как нелепый председатель сделал перерыв." (emphasis mine).

Comment: "Разработаться" is rather common in technics, meaning some joint lost flexibility (dried/cold grease or metal rots or something) but as it get forcefully moved back and forth it gets better and better, easier and easier. Or maybe some tight hole with some rather thick rod inside. As one moves the rod it kind of enlarges the hole until having enough room to move with ease.

Answer (score 2):

These words have slightly negative (or ironical) connotation in the modern language (*что-то ты, брат, рас…ся*).

Since "dreaming" or "shouting" too much can have undesired consequences and hence fit for this connotation, the words from your second list still live, but those from the first list are almost extinct (though the paradigm is productive and the constructed words can be used rhetorically, as intended barbarisms):

> - Товарищ первый нам сказал, что вы уймитесь,
>     Что — не буяньте, говорит, что — разойдитесь.
>     Ну, на "разойтись" я, кстати, тут же согласился —
>     И разошёлся, то есть расходился!
>
>   *Высоцкий В., "Милицейский протокол", 1971*
> - Потом и я разработался и, соответственно, произведения стали получаться все лучше и лучше. *[proza.ru](http://www.proza.ru/rec_author.html?bahmat)*
> - Первый раз я серьёзно раздумался о своей будущности. *[И. И. Панаев. Раздел имения (1850-1860)]*
> - Когда лежал в госпитале, «расчитался» от нечего делать и теперь, как без наркотика, не мог без этого, без Лерочкиной «Бовари». *[Андрей Житков. Супермаркет (2000)]*

In the last example the word is clearly marked as constructed.

Note that the word *раздумался* had been used neutrally along with the modern *задумался* at least till the beginning of the XX century. [This graph](http://goo.gl/Q608N) shows it quite cleary.

Comment: Strange, [this table](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&t2=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&start=1800&end=2010&smoothing=3) actually tells me that раздуматься has always been rare, but задуматься was not.

Comment: @Olga: one of the meanings of *задуматься* is "to be lost in thoughts", another one "to hesitate". *Раздуматься* lacks both. But they could have been used in parallel in the meaning you asked about, yes, I should have written "along with" rather than "instead of". What I wanted to tell is that its meaning "to start thinking thoroughly" was quite popular in XIX and almost lost now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of previous answers. The word "разработаться" is perfectly valid, and, in fact have several meanings (though most marked as colloquial), including a special one. Only first one may have an ironic or negative comnnotatation:

- Войти в работу; разохотиться работать. / To start working good and eagerly.

  > Так разработался, что и про обед забыл. ([Толковый словарь Ефремовой](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/235107/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F))
- Работая, действуя, прийти в хорошее рабочее состояние (о механизмах) / To start working properly (about mechanisms)

  > Замок разработался. Подожди, пока мотор разработается. ([Толковый словарь русского языка Кузнецова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/kuznetsov/51711/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F))
- Начать нормально работать (о ранее поврежденных частях тела) / To start working properly (about previously injured parts of a body).

  > Пальцы на руке почти вылечил — хотя они еще не разработались, все же смогли бы, наверно, управиться с винтовкой. Евдокимов, Была похоронка. ([Малый академический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/mas/58174/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F))
- В работе износиться, перестать быть годным. / To wear-off due to intensive usage.

  > Шестерня разработалась. Винт, гайка разработались. ([Толковый словарь Ушакова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/999118))

Answer (score 1):

*Раз...ся* has the meaning “to do something **out**”.

1. Sounds pretty OK, just not frequent. Usually **you** work something out (*ты разраба́тываешь* / *вы разраба́тываете*), not the thing itself. (But there is *расстара́ться*).
2. Really don’t know. But you can say *зачита́ться*.
3. Thinking is about concentration, not disconcentration, so you can for ex. *заду́маться* (like fall **in** thinking), but not *разду́маться*.

Russian word generating model is quite powerful, not all possible combination are in use.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the actual meaning of the verb prefixes is not 'start doing something and become good at it', but rather 'to exceed planned limits of action'.

Therefore it is natural to say that one has 'shouted/written/scheduled' more than had planned - which might be one-person, or non-communicative actions -  but it is almost impossible to say the same thing about work, reading or thinking - which might be conceptually polipersonal, or communicative actions.